# jQuery find function not worked as expected

Tags: jquery

```js
var firstValue = $(this).find('.feedback-selected').val();
var secondValue = $('.feedback-selected').val();
alert(firstValue);
alert(secondValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input class="feedback-selected" type="hidden" value="4" />
</div>
```

This might sound a little dumb, but can you please point out why in the following script 'firstValue' is undefined and 'secondValue' is as needed, i.e. 4.

I am sure I am not using the find function as it should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**this** doesn't have a value in your example, so the find() function will not find anything.

(**this** is only valid in instance functions or event handlers)

Comment: The edit made to my answer is not correct. $(this) does have a value, although with no DOM elements in it, but "this" is undefined (and that's the reason for the error the OP is getting)

Comment: I didn't change that wording. I changed from just "this" to "$(this)" as the two are different things.

Comment: Thanks dude, I knew I was doing something dumb.

Comment: I wanted to point out that "this" was undefined (no value). If I would have said "$(this) doesn't have a value", that would be wrong, because it does. $(undefined) returns a valid jQuery object

Comment: But even saying this is only valid in instance functions or event handlers doesn't quite address it's usage in the example. What matters is what it references. Does it reference a DOM element? 
"this" can be manipulated with apply. Might be a good idea to reference the other answer as well that talks about "this" as used by jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

[Explanation of what 'this' means in jQuery](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/)

Answer (score 0):

What activa said... and you could probably use $(document) instead of $(this) if you need to use .find()

Answer (score 0):

activa's answer is correct. `$("<selector>")` is the equivalent of what you were trying to do with the first search. `find("<selector>")` is meant for searching within a wrapped set, not as a starting point.

However, I would add that a better way of retrieving the value in this case is:

```
var value = $("input.feedback-selected").val();
```

This is because including the type of the element will allow jQuery to search the DOM in a quicker way.

Answer (score 0):

find() searches for descendant elements of the jQuery object you call it on. You call find() on the results of $(this), which is nothing. If you want to call find() on the document, you'll have to use $(document).

Answer (score 0):

`this` in your example is not a DOM element that contains any subelements of class "feedback-selected", so the find function can't find them. It might not even be a DOM element.

I would note that $(this) can be valid anywhere this points to a DOM element. So if pretty much anytime you're triggering a function that is called from a DOM element, you're fine. It's all about the scope in this case. This would be valid too:

```
function aha() {
 alert($(this).find('.feedback-selected').val());
}

aha.apply(document);
```